# How to package multimodule library as one jar

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a library consisted of sever modules and I would like to package and publish it as a single artifact. Here is a fragment of my build.sbt

```
lazy val root = Project(id = "root",
  base = file(".")) aggregate(module1, module2)

lazy val module1 = Project(id = "module1",
  base = file("module1"))

lazy val module2 = Project(id = "module2",
  base = file("module2")) dependsOn module1
```

When I run `sbt package` I only get an almost empty jar(with just manifest inside) in root `target`. I don't want to use `sbt-assembly` because dependencies should be managed by published pom, not packaged inside published jar. Publishing 3 artifacts, where root is an empty artifact depending on modules, is also an acceptable option.

Comment: did you try the sbt-native-packager? https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works, at least for `package` (haven't tried to `publish`):

```
lazy val root = Project(id = "root", base = file("."))
  .aggregate(module1, module2)
  .settings(
    mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ++= {
      val mod1 = (mappings in (module1, Compile, packageBin)).value
      val mod2 = (mappings in (module2, Compile, packageBin)).value
      mod1 ++ mod2
    }
  )

lazy val module1 = Project(id = "module1",
  base = file("module1"))

lazy val module2 = Project(id = "module2",
  base = file("module2")) dependsOn module1
```

The mappings are briefly described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Package.html#Modify+the+contents+of+the+package).